# Dependent dropdowns to be added dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, dynamically-generated

I have a JSON object which contains categories and corresponding sub-categories.I have two dropdowns(as a row of a table), first dropdown contains the category list.When a particular category is selected, the second dropdown gets populated with the sub-catogories of the selected category.
I have done this and is working fine.

Now, I have the requirement to add rows dynamically.Add row functionality is also working fine.

But I am not able to establish relation between the dropdowns in dynamically added rows.

I know the reason why - I am not able to assign id to the dynamically created dropdowns and hense am not able to establish any relationship between them.

Please suggest how to establish the required relationship.

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<form id="myForm">
<TABLE id="dataTable" >
<TR><TD>
<select id="selectCategory" onchange="GetSelectedItem()">
<option>Choose a category</option>
</select>
</TD>
<TD>
<select id="selectSubCategory" >
<option>Choose a sub-category</option>
</select>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</form>
```

Script:

```
    <script><!--
var jsonObj={"category1":["subcat 1"],"category2":["subcat 2.1","subcat 2.2"],"category3":["subcat 3.1","subcat 3.2","subcat 3.3"]};
var keys= Object.keys(jsonObj);
    var category_dropdown = document.getElementById("selectCategory"); 
for (var keys in jsonObj)    {              
    category_dropdown[category_dropdown.length] = new Option(keys,keys);        
    }
function GetSelectedItem()      {
            var e = document.getElementById("selectCategory");
            var selectedCategory = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

            var sub_category_dropdown = document.getElementById("selectSubCategory");   
            document.getElementById("selectSubCategory").options.length=0; //clearing previous values of the drop-down list
            for(var i=0;i<jsonObj[selectedCategory].length;i++)             {
                sub_category_dropdown[sub_category_dropdown.length] = new Option(jsonObj[selectedCategory][i],jsonObj[selectedCategory][i]);    
            }
    }
function addRow(tableID) 
    {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID); 
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
         var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
             newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
             newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;

        }
    }
//--></script>
```

Comment: What should the dynamically created row have as input when you click on it?
It is unclear what is the desired relationship ...

Comment: I want the dynamically created row to have two dropdowns - first for category and second from sub-category.Now,when I click on the Add row button, two dropdowns are getting added, but the two dropdowns have no relationship between each other. i,e., when I select category1 in the first dropdown(dynamically added) , the sub-categories are not getting populated in the second dropdown(dynamically added).

Comment: Yes I understand now, can you use jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is not an option for me (some firm restrictions). Can this be achieved without jQuery?

Comment: Yes it can, hold on, I'll show you some piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you enter a dynamically created element you have to attach the events to it as well, with jquery you can delegate events, but because you don't use it so on the `addRow` function I added the eventListener.

**But** you are creating dynamic elements with the same ID, this is wrong, HTML specifies one ID per element.
So you should change your IDs into class and have a specific ID for each row element.
Because HTML works even if it's broken, I added a little check to the code to see if it's the initial row or a dynamically created one, so you can know to which one of the select boxes (with the same ID) to attach the event listener (`getElementById` returns the first it finds).
So this will work but it's really bad practice.

I've added just a bit of jQuery into the mix but you can take it out, just for the event listeners.

This is the jsfiddle of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/C2xsj/5/

and here is the HTML

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" id="button"/>
<form id="myForm">
<TABLE id="dataTable" >
<TR><TD>
<select id="selectCategory">
<option>Choose a category</option>
</select>
</TD>
<TD>
<select id="selectSubCategory" >
<option>Choose a sub-category</option>
</select>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</form>
```

and the code

```
$(function () {
    $('#selectCategory').change(function() {
        getSelectedItem(this, null);
    });

    $('#button').click(function() {
        addRow('dataTable');
    });

    var jsonObj = {"category1":["subcat 1"],"category2":["subcat 2.1","subcat 2.2"],"category3":["subcat 3.1","subcat 3.2","subcat 3.3"]};
var keys = Object.keys(jsonObj);
var category_dropdown = document.getElementById("selectCategory"); 

var getSelectedItem = function(element, row) {
    var e = element;
    var selectedCategory = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var sub_category_dropdown = (row != null ? row.getElementsByTagName("select")[1] : document.getElementById("selectSubCategory"));
    sub_category_dropdown.options.length=0;
    for (var i=0;i<jsonObj[selectedCategory].length;i++) {
        sub_category_dropdown[sub_category_dropdown.length] = new Option(jsonObj[selectedCategory][i],jsonObj[selectedCategory][i]);
    }
};

var addRow = function(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID); 
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

       for (var i = 0; i<colCount; i++) {
             var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
             newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
             newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
    }
    var selects = row.getElementsByTagName("select");
    selects[0].addEventListener('change', function() { getSelectedItem(this, row) }, false);
};

    for (var keys in jsonObj) {              
        category_dropdown[category_dropdown.length] = new Option(keys,keys);        
    }   
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...It really helped me.  Just out of curosity, my categories and sub-catogories are stores in sqlite db.I am fetching it using perl and then using JSON module to encode it.This object is then used by Javascript to render the dropdown.Is it the correct approach? Please suggest better alternatives , if any. Thanks again.

Comment: Well do you have to use perl for it? PHP has it's own `PDO` with SQLite built in, you could fetch it with `AJAX` if you'd like ... depends on your project really ...